# Upgrading a Synology DS416slim NAS

Tags: nas, raid

To be clear: I haven't bought anything yet, so I figure this is a hardware recommendation question. The point is that I don't want to buy hardware with too much built-in obsolescence.

I'm looking at a replacement for some aging Drobos. I like the look of the small Synology 2.5in desktop (for reasons of space) and wondered if anyone had experience with them.

Specifically, I want to start out using 4x1Tb drives, and then when the price drops (assumption!) in 2-3 years time swap them out (gradually, 1 at a time over a week or so) for 2 or 3Tb drives.

I believe that Synology has SHR (?) that will let me do this, but that until all the drives have been replaced with larger drives the overall volume will remain at 4Tb.

Can anyone confirm that this is indeed the case? Are there any gotcha's I should know about?

Is Synology the way to go, or should I be looking at other hardware options?

Comment: Welcome to Hardware Recommendations! Unfortunately, we do not cover tech support questions here. [Super User](http://superuser.com) should be able to help you with your question.

Comment: This is not a tech support question. I have not yet bought anything. I have rephrased to make this clear. If something other than Synology is better then I'm open to that too.

Comment: @Dycey "Haven't bought anything" doesn't necessarily make a question not tech support.

Comment: So, "can I drive up a mountain in this real wheel drive car, or should I get some other car?" is a tech support question? Interesting.